# Capture text using regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to capture a text in javascript. The string is in the following format.

`*** Aug 29 2010 3:32PM username: and more texts in here`

I want to capture the username from the text. How can I do that using regex? I tried many different things, but none produced what I wanted. The username can contain numbers but not symbols, and are one word.

Comment: Is username one word or it could be many words?

Comment: @MaxZoom it is one word.

Comment: To write a regex we need more than one example, can you show more examples? Also, if the snippet you have is not the full text, can you show all of it?

Comment: @ThatWeirdo sorry I can't show full text. They contain personal information. All the text is preceded by the above text; and the notes are always started with the text above. I just need to capture the username, and out of 124,678 notes, all of them start with the date time (in the format shown above) and the username followed by ":"

Comment: @adamdc78 Better now? LOL

Comment: So you need to capture the part that's after the colon? In that case, is the username one word? Does it contain numbers? Symbols? Etc...

Comment: @ThatWeirdo, it's like any other username. It can contain number but no symbols. And no. I just need to capture the "username" which is between the time (AM|PM) and colon(:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume the hour is always displayed this way and the final `:` is always present :

`/\d:\d\d\S\S (.*?):/g`

should capture the username and store it in first capture group properly.

**Demo 1 :** https://www.regex101.com/r/pR7eT5/1

**Demo 2 :** https://www.debuggex.com/r/NSlFDyt9toMCu7nJ

Comment: This one is capturing the time as well. I don't need time, but just the username

Comment: No, it's not. Take a closer look : the capturing parenthesis are around the expected username.

Comment: I don't understand. What am I doing wrong then? Could you please check? Here's an example I'm trying. `newStr.replace(/\d:\d\d\S\S (.*?):/g, "<span class='label label-success'>$&</span>");` But when I do this, it highlights both the username and the time.

Comment: Ok so you are doing it this way. I didn't expected that. Then, you should do this way : `newStr.replace(/(\d:\d\d(?:AM|PM) )(.*?):/g, "$1<span class='label label-success'>$2</span>:");`

Comment: There you go. That's it. That's what I need. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user1828605, I believe my attempt (first one posted btw) that you down-voted offered the same answer as the one you accepted.

Comment: @alpha bravo, it's not me who downvoted your answer. I just said it didn't give me what I wanted, could be cause I didn't know what I was doing. But I didn't downvote. I don't like it when people downvote, but doesn't leave a comment why it's downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

A simple regex:

```
\w+(?::)
```

This is for a username before a colon.

If you want a more specific one that has to be between a time and a colon then use:

```
(?:AM|PM)(?: )\w+(?::)
```

You're welcome to test it with your data here: [RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/)

Simply paste the Regex in the first box and your data in the second.

**Edit:**
For some reason non-capturing groups don't matter to JS replace, so we can just use capturing groups to divide the info in pieces:

```
var info = document.getElementById('info');
var newStr = info.innerHTML;
newStr = newStr.replace(/(AM|PM) (\w+):/g, '$1 <span class="label label-success">$2</span>:');
info.innerHTML = newStr;
```

*Assuming the element with `id="info"` has the data

## Demo

Comment: I just tried, it also picks up AM. Here try this. `*** Sep 5 2014 8:31AM user1: ade3werw- asdfawsedaf`. or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I really do not understand :(. It still highlights AM|PM and the username. What am I doing wrong? :( :(

Comment: Besides, I'm trying to do this in javascript. Could it have anything to do with it? I'm also doing this to highlight the username. `newStr.replace(/(?:AM|PM)(?: )\w+(?::)/, '<span class="label label-success">$&</span>');`

Comment: RegexPal shows you the whole match, but if you use this regex in something like a JavaScript replace or match or anything, it should only give you the name, nothing more. RegexPal is merely a good tool for testing

Comment: @user1828605 I've edited to supply a solution that works, though I wonder why JS replace doesn't care about non-capturing groups. But this will do

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me. I had already gotten the answer from Ninetainedo. I upvoted this since it works and what I needed. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

A simple one would be 
`str.replace(/.* (.*):/, "$1");`

That takes your string and captures the text between the last space and the colon in $1, and then replaces the string with that.

- /.* / # ignore everything until the last space
- /(.*):/ # capture all the characters until a colon

Comment: This won't work if there is a space in the username. In that case I think you would want something that finds the AM or PM and then goes from there until the end. `str.replace(/.*?([AP]M) (.*):/, "$2");`

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain that the user name is one world and it is after the date, then you can use the postion after spliting the string with a space

```js
var line = "*** Aug 29 2010 3:32PM username: and more texts in here";
var user = line.split(' ', 6)[5].replace('\:', '');
alert(user)
```

Or use only the regex for matching string: `3:32PM username:`

```js
var line = "*** Aug 29 2010 3:32PM username: and more texts in here";
var regex = /(\d:\d\d(?:AM|PM) )(.*?):/
alert(regex.exec(line)[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the `AM` OR `PM` inside a non-capturing group `(?:)` followed by a blank space  `\s`

Capture then `()` any word character `w+` (`+`is for *more than one*)

Between the previous set and the literal symbol `:`

```
(?:AM|PM)\s(\w+):
```

***[Live example](https://regex101.com/r/cW3cI7/2)***

So if you want a function to simplify the retrieval of the username you can do like:

```
function getUsername( str ) {
  return (/(?:AM|PM)\s(\w+):/.exec(str)||'')[1];
}

var userName = getUsername("*** Aug 29 2010 3:32PM username: and more texts in here");
```

The above will successfully return the needed username or `undefined` if no match was found.

Answer (score -1):

you could use this pattern

```
:\S+\s([^:]+)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cF9oW4/4)

```
:               # ":"
\S              # <not a whitespace character>
+               # (one or more)(greedy)
\s              # <whitespace character>
(               # Capturing Group (1)
  [^:]          # Character not in [^:]
  +             # (one or more)(greedy)
)               # End of Capturing Group (1)
```

Comment: it replaced the preceding AM|PM as well.

Comment: I believe you're wrong, check against capturing group.

Comment: @user1828605 Wait wait wait, you want to replace? Or just capture?

Answer (score -1):

You can do this faster without regex:

```
str.split(' ').slice(5).join(' ').slice(0, -1);
```

Comment: @shbeewah, this would've worked if I didn't have any other texts after the username. Apparently, it wasn't very clear from my question.

Comment: @user1828605 That's not a problem, you can just replace slice(5) with slice(5, 6). It is always best to avoid regex where possible. You almost always get a better solution without it.